# How to lock Windows 10 screen without turn off?

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, lock, windows-10-v21h1

Is it possible to lock screen without screen turn off? For example, here is my settings:

[image]

I wanna automatically lock screen after 5 minutes, but display should not off (only after 30 minutes).

I thought "Sign-in options - Require sign-in" option responses for this:

[image]

But this does not work — screen is locked only after 30 minutes along turn off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open Settings.
- Click on Personalization.
- Click on Lock screen.
- Click the Screen saver settings link near the bottom.
- Set a screensaver to run after x minutes.
- Click the checkbox "On resume, display logon screen".
- Make sure your user account has a password.

Comment: +1 so glad that this question and answer exist. Amazing how out-of-the-way and counter-intuitive/illogical this setting is (and how *insecure* it is that disabling or delaying screen-offing and computer-sleeping leads to the computer also remaining unlocked).